# Replace characters in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to replace characters starting from a specific position in string but it seems to only replace and remove characters at the beginning let's say I am trying to replace this:

```
0000000000
```

with

```
00AAAAAA00
```

The first two and the last two characters should not be replaced. However when using this query

```
Update Table1
set col1=replace(col1,'0','A',2,8)
where Table1.col2='R';
```

I get this

```
AAAAAAAA0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The first two and the last two characters should not be replaced."*

`Left(col1, 2)` will give you the first two characters and `Right(col1, 2)` will give you the last two.

Seems you want 6 "A" characters in between them; `String(6, 'A')` will give you that.

```sql
Update Table1
set col1 = Left(col1, 2) & String(6, 'A') & Right(col1, 2)
where Table1.col2 = 'R';
```

If you prefer to use `Replace()`, adjust the *start* position and the *count* of substitutions to perform.

```sql
Update Table1
set col1 = Left(col1, 2) & replace(col1, '0', 'A', 3, 6)
where Table1.col2 = 'R';
```